# How can I run one command to bundle libraries and output separately in vue-cli3.0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bundle, vue-cli-3

I have read the document of [build library](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#app) in VUE-CLI3.0.
My directory:

```
--src
  --components
    --componentA.vue
    --componentB.vue
    ....
    --componentZ.vue
--build
  --libs.js
```

I want to run one command with my one entry "**libs.js**" ***(Maybe there is a loop to create multiple entries in libs.js)*** to bundle my components **separately**. The destination folder maybe like the following:

```
--dist
  --componentA.css
  --componentA.command.js
  --componentA.umd.js
  --componentA.umd.min.js
  ...
  --componentZ.css
  --componentZ.command.js
  --componentZ.umd.js
  --componentZ.umd.min.js
```

Can anyone give me some suggetions?

Comment: try `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib 'src/components/*.vue'`

Comment: @cal_br_mar. Thanks for your reply. But the above will cost me much time on entering the command if I have many components.

Comment: How do you import them after can you just do `import ComponentA from 'dist'` ?

Comment: @MarineLeBorgne. After building these components, I can use them by adding a script tag or `import CompontA from 'dist/ComponentA.umd.js'`. I just want to keep the UI uniform on ES5 developed environment or ES6+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a script file. In which, I get the list of components and using 'child_process' to execute each command. 
The following is an example:

**lib.js**

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process')

const glob = require('glob')
// console font color
const chalk = require('chalk')
// loading
const ora = require('ora')

// 获取所有的moduleList
const components = glob.sync('./src/components/*.vue')
// const buildFile = path.join(__dirname, 'build.js')
// const webpack = require('vuec')
const spinner = ora('Packaging the components...\n').start()
setTimeout(() => {
  spinner.stop()
}, 2000)

for (const component of components) {
  // const file = path.join(__dirname, module);
  const name = component.substring(component.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).slice(0, -4)

  const cmd = `vue build -t lib -n ${name} ${component} -d lib/components/${name}`
  execSync(cmd)

  console.log(chalk.blue(`Component ${name} is packaged.`))
}
console.log(`[${new Date()}]` + chalk.green('Compeleted !'))
```

**What's more**, add a script command in package.json:
`"build-all": "node ./src/build/lib.js"`

You just enter `npm run build-all`. That's all~